# How do you apply security rules to Firepad?

Tags: firebase, firebase-security, firepad

I'd like to secure a Firepad. After my research, I discovered https://github.com/firebase/firepad/tree/master/examples/security, which lists some rules in .json for securing a Firepad. I have looked extensively at the [Firepad docs](http://www.firepad.io/docs/#api), but cannot figure out how to apply the [example security rules](https://github.com/firebase/firepad/tree/master/examples/security) when initializing a Firepad.

How do you initialize a Firepad using the example security rules embedded in JSON (referred to above)?

**EDIT 01:**
I can see that Firebase lets you configure the rules, I'm interested in finding out how to APPLY these rules. For example, if I initialize a Firepad like this:

```
var firepadRef = new Firebase('MYURL');
var codeMirror = CodeMirror(document.getElementById('firepad'), { lineWrapping: true });
var firepad = Firepad.fromCodeMirror(firepadRef, codeMirror,
    { richTextShortcuts: true, richTextToolbar: true, defaultText: 'Hello, World!' });
```

how do I incorporate the rules in JSON? As an option to the `Firepad.fromCodeMirror()` call? As some sort of parameter to the `new Firebase()` call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you haven't already, you'll probably want to learn a bit about [Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/), the backend for Firepad.  As part of setting up Firepad, you'll create a Firebase account and a Firebase database.  The Firebase database lets you configure [Security Rules](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/) by entering them in the "Security & Rules" tab of your the dashboard (or uploading them via the [REST API](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/api/#section-security-rules)).

To be clear, the security rules are *not* set via the code that initializes Firepad, since that is untrusted code running in the browser and so any user of your app could modify it.

Comment: I can see that Firebase lets you configure the rules, I'm interested in finding out how to APPLY these rules. See edit above...

Comment: Okay.  I updated the answer.  Hopefully it's clearer.